# error: the following arguments are required: -a/--az, -m/--model

Tags: python, argparse

So I'm following this tutorial https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/08/17/ocr-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/ The problem is that when I run my code, the training file for the OCR that I'm creating this error appears.
[image]

I don't know why this happen, this is the code that is showing the error

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-a", "--az", required=True, help="path to A-Z dataset")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", type=str, required=True, help="path to output trained 
handwritten recognition model")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--plot", type=str, 
default="C:/Users/berna/Desktop/Programming/AI_ML_DL/Projects/OCRApp_phototext/plot.png", 
help="path to output training history file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

Any idea?

Comment: this isn't a programming issue. when a program tells you "usage: ...", you need to read that, understand it, and satisfy the program's requirement by passing the requested command line switches. questions on the usage of random programs are *likely* off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the program uses `ArgumentParser` you need to pass arguments when running it, simply typing `python train_ocr_model.py` won't do it, after tying the file name you need to add the missing parameters it is asking for like `-a`, here is an example:

```
python train_ocr_model.py --az a_z_handwritten_data.csv --model handwriting.model
```

The `help` parameter tells you what each argument needs as input.

Comment: Please note that you need the files `a_z_handwritten_data.csv` & `handwriting.model` to be present in that directory.